# Google App Engine doesn't find local python module

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, module, gae-module

For some reason when I uploaded my app engine project yesterday (before this, everything worked fine), it can't find one of my .py files/modules. My directory is as follows:

```
app_directory/
  gaesessions/
    __init__.py
  lib/
    httplib2/
      __init__.py
      other stuff
  app.yaml
  appengine_config.py
  index.yaml
  All other .py files/modules
```

For some reason I now get the following error:

```
import_string() failed for 'games.GetMyGames'. Possible reasons are:

- missing __init__.py in a package;
- package or module path not included in sys.path;
- duplicated package or module name taking precedence in sys.path;
- missing module, class, function or variable;

Original exception:

ImportError: cannot import name GameModel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized I had a circular import:

in File1.py

```
from File2 import class1
```

and in File2.py

```
from File1 import class3
```

I changed to:
in File1.py

```
import File2
```

and in File2.py

```
import File1
```

and I moved all of my class imports from File1 and File2 further down the files and this solved my issue. Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: Yes.. circular imports are evil and usually the error message are not going to tell you that :)

Comment: So circular imports would still work on a local environment but not when deployed?